# How to scroll to an element which is not inside the viewport in Appium?

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am using appium java client with uiautomator2 as the automation engine for android. The application has a scrollview from which I need to fetch text off TextView. some of those are within the viewport when the screen is loaded and some of those are outside viewport. How can I fetch the text of the nodes in a right way? Right now, I have a specific test device on which I know which element is visible and which is not. So for the later, I have implemented a scrollTo method to scroll down to.

I have seen solutions on keeping scrolling until the element is in viewport. I didn't like it as it will hamper the performance of the tests. because the test could still be waiting for an element before scrolling next and that time is simply wasted.

What could be a better strategy to handle this? We are using pagefactory pattern and mostly using xpath, accessibility label and id to identify the elements. In case it helps, the app under test is a react native app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using [UiScrollable](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/UiScrollable) for that.

If you use page object pattern and `@AndroidFindBy` annotation, you can simply put:

```java
@AndroidFindBy(uiSelector = "UiScrollable(\"className(\"android.widget.ScrollView\")\").scrollIntoView(resourceId(\"id_of_element_to_scroll_to\"))")
private MobileElement buttonOfTheScreen;
```

Here you need to define two locators:

- one for the element which will be swiped on, let call it *swipe base* - `className(\"android.widget.ScrollView\")` in the example above
- the second locator is for element that is out of the screen - `resourceId(\"id_of_element_to_scroll_to\")`

No additional actions are required. Once you need to interact with your element, e.g. `getText()` or `click()`, uiautomator will swipe to it automatically.

Alternatively, you can use:

```java
String locator = "UiScrollable(\"className(\"android.widget.ScrollView\")\").scrollIntoView(resourceId(\"id_of_element_to_scroll_to\"))";
driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(locator)).click();
```

**Note:** this approach works only if the element you are looking for is under the bottom edge of your screen.